# How to update Entity retrieved with EntityManager.find

Tags: jpa

After I retrieve an Entity with `EntityManager.find`, the changes to the Entity (via its setters) are not persisted.

I am reading that changes to a managed Entity were supposed to be persisted automatically and that an Entity retrieved via `find` is managed. But that does not seem to be happening. If I want changes to persist, I have been having to do a find, make the change, then call `merge` on the Entity that was just retrieved via `find`. This does not seem right.

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;


public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        MyEntity state = entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, 1);
        state.setX( state.getX()+1 );

        java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><head><title>Servlet Tester</title></head><body>");
        out.println("Servlet Test Page<br>");
        out.println("(X = " + state.getX() + ")");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }
}
```

The entity is simply:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class MyEntity
{
    @Id
    int id;
    int x;

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

In the output to the web page I can see that the value of `x` is 1 greater than the value of x in the database, so the increment is happening just as it appears, but the database is not updated with the new value, and the next time the page is visited the value retrieved by the `find` is still the old value.

If I add in `entityManager.merge(state);` after setting a value, then I can successfully save the updates. However, from what I have been reading, it does not sound like this should be necessary, as I have read from multiple sources that a managed Entity should be persisting these changes automatically when the Entity is updated. Also, I have read that calling `merge` is less efficient than getting the container to commit its queued changes when it is supposed to. Since I am updating the Entity immediately after `find`ing it, it should not be inactive.

How do I get the Entity to persist updates automatically as is expected?

### My Environment

Hibernate/JBoss

### What I have tried

I have tried using Stateless and Stateful session beans, hoping that they would hint to the container that there was some kind of transaction going on that it needed to clean up after.

My Stateful session bean workaround only worked when I added a `save` method to the Stateful session bean which explicitly called `entityManager.merge(state);`, so that isn't really any different than what I mentioned above about needing to call `merge`.

So, **how do I get my Entity to actually be managed correctly, to persist updates to the Entity?**

Comment: Please also mention your JPA and Hibernate versions.

Comment: You don't have a transaction. Therefore no changes are saved to the database. Do want to keep that in the Servlet or use EJBs? If you use EJBs the transactions are automatically there.

Comment: Not all JPA providers allow non-transactional updates to entities. Yours apparently doesn't, so create a transaction

Answer (score 0):

TL.DR;

> After I retrieve an Entity with EntityManager.find, the changes to the Entity (via its setters) are not persisted.

In the shared code, there isn't any synchronization call with the data base, depend on your requirement you can use `flush` or `commit`.If you have transactional behavior you can [flush](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) till you finish your transaction task then commit it.

```html
T t = entityManager.find(YoutClassType.class, primary_key)
//Do some update logic
...
entityManager.flush();
```

You can also use [CriteriaUpdate](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaUpdate.html) api for criteria base updating.

```html
CriteriaUpdate<T> criteriaUpdate = criteriaBuilder.createCriteriaUpdate(updateType);
Root<T> updateRoot = criteriaUpdate.from(updateType);
criteriaUpdate.set(updateRoot.get(your_field_for_update), s);
entityManager.createQuery(criteriaUpdate.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(updateRoot.get("field_to+match"), v))).executeUpdate();
```